# Mockito: mock instance method for all instances of a class

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm trying to stub an instance method of a particular class, so that when any instance of this `Foo` class calls this instance method `doSomething`, the same `object` is returned (see code below). However, mockito doesn't allow any matchers outside of verification or stubbing.

```
Bar object = new Bar();
given(any(Foo.class).doSomething(Arg.class)).willReturn(object);
```

And in `Foo.class`:

```
Bar doSomething(Arg param) {
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    // Do something with bar
    return bar;
}
```

Any way I can achieve this goal with Mockito? Thanks!

Comment: well a solution without dirty hackarounds would be a private method with a `boolean` parameter for returning the same value. Then your public methods would call that one (Since you're attempting to look for a self-caller). Outside of that, you're looking at reading the stack.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in scala?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use **PowerMock** if you want `Foo` to return the same instance of `Bar` when you call `doSomething` method on any instance of `Foo`. Here's an example:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Foo.class)
public class FooMockAllInstanceTest {

    @Test
    public void testMockInstanceofObjectCreation() throws Exception {
        Bar mockBar = PowerMockito.mock(Bar.class);
        when(mockBar.sayHello()).thenReturn("Hi John!");
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Bar.class)
                .withNoArguments()
                .thenReturn(mockBar);

        Foo myFooOne = new Foo();
        assertEquals(mockBar,  myFooOne.doSomething("Jane"));

        Foo myFooTwo = new Foo();
        assertEquals(mockBar,  myFooTwo.doSomething("Sarah"));

        Baz bazOne = new Baz();
        assertEquals(mockBar, bazOne.doSomething("Sam"));

        Baz bazTwo = new Baz();
        assertEquals(mockBar, bazTwo.doSomething("Nina"));
    }
}
```

This example will return the same `Bar` object even when `Baz` is called. Here's the `Baz` class,

```
public class Baz {

    public Bar doSomething(String name) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        return foo.doSomething(name);
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

There's another slightly better way to test with PowerMock. Here it's,

```
@Test
public void testStubbingMethod() throws Exception {
    Bar mockBar = PowerMockito.mock(Bar.class);
    when(mockBar.sayHello()).thenReturn("Hi John!");

    PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(Foo.class, "doSomething",
            String.class)).toReturn(mockBar);

    Foo myFooOne = new Foo();
    assertEquals(mockBar, myFooOne.doSomething("Jane"));

    Foo myFooTwo = new Foo();
    assertEquals(mockBar, myFooTwo.doSomething("Sarah"));

    Baz bazOne = new Baz();
    assertEquals(mockBar, bazOne.doSomething("Sam"));

    Baz bazTwo = new Baz();
    assertEquals(mockBar, bazTwo.doSomething("Nina"));
}
```

Comment: A good start - and nice that you left some room for conceptual explanations within my answer ;-)

Comment: This does not look like it solves the OP's problem. OP wants that calling method `doSomething` on **any** instance of **`Foo`** should return a particular object. In this answer, only if the method is called on this particular `Foo` instance, which is the private member of class `FooTest`, will the particular object be returned. Suppose that the class being tested is `Baz` which has its own instance of `Foo` and calls `doSomething` on it in one of its methods, it is the **real** `doSomething` method that will get called, and that is **not** the desired behavior.

Comment: It helped a lot to handle instances internally created with the class to be tested. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I found this page to tell "How to mock construction of new objects"

https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor#example

```
// Class to be tested and need mock File object

public class PersistenceManager {

    public boolean createDirectoryStructure(String directoryPath) {
        File directory = new File(directoryPath);

        if (directory.exists()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("\"" + directoryPath + "\" already exists.");
        }

        return directory.mkdirs();
    }
}
```

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import java.io.File;

import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.*;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( PersistenceManager.class )
public class PersistenceManagerTest {

    @Test
    public void testCreateDirectoryStructure_ok() throws Exception {
        final String path = "directoryPath";
        File fileMock = createMock(File.class);

        PersistenceManager tested = new PersistenceManager();

        expectNew(File.class, path).andReturn(fileMock);

        expect(fileMock.exists()).andReturn(false);
        expect(fileMock.mkdirs()).andReturn(true);

        replay(fileMock, File.class);

        assertTrue(tested.createDirectoryStructure(path));

        verify(fileMock, File.class);
    }
}
```